PHPSpreadsheet password protected or enrypt file
I'm trying to password protect excel file
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;

$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
$activeWorksheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
$activeWorksheet->setCellValue('A1', 'Hello World !');
$spreadsheet->getSecurity()->setLockWindows(true);
$spreadsheet->getSecurity()->setLockStructure(true);
$spreadsheet->getSecurity()->setWorkbookPassword("123456");

Above code is not protecting the file
I used encrypt method
use Nick\SecureSpreadsheet\Encrypt;
$test = new Encrypt($nofile = true);
$output = $test->input($binaryData)
    ->password('111')
    ->output();

How to get the binary data from phpspreadsheet output?
$writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
$fileName = 'staff_data.xlsx';
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'. urlencode($fileName).'"');
$writer->save('php://output');


I'm unclear of your question. Your first code block didn't work, but I can't tell if the second one did or did not, and then I'm not sure how the third block relates to the first two.

In your implementation the encrypted spreadsheet is only store in variable $output.
To send it to the browser you'll have to output the contents of that variable, e.g. use echo $output instead of $writer->save('php://output');
If $output is not available when you want to return content to the browser you should consider saving the spreadsheet to a file and then return that file via readfile($youFileName).
Saving the spreadsheet can be done by using this:
$test->input($binaryData)
    ->password('111')
    ->output('/the/path/to/your/file.xslx');

Then send the file to the browser like this:
$fileName = '/the/path/to/your/file.xslx';
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . urlencode($fileName) . '"');
readfile($fileName);

